# expire stored sessions from all browsers once password is changed - Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Seems like Prestashop doesn't have this functionality out of the box. So, is there any way to do it?

I know, I've to setup timestamp in a table w.r.t the session, change it on password change, and query it on every page load to check if it matches. But, where do I start in Prestashop?

Comment: why do you think that it is possible?

Comment: but why not????

Comment: I've opened site in my browser, site created session and stored session cookie on my computer, I've disconnected my desktop from internet, how you can delete it now?

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant expire....